# Using Python requests to GET not working - web client and browser works

Tags: python, rest, flask, python-requests

I have my web app API running.

If I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ via any browser I get the right response.

If I use the Advanced REST Client Chrome app and send a GET request to my app at that address I get the right response.

However this gives me a 503:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
```

I read to try this for some reason:

```
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
```

But I still get a 503 response.

Other things I've tried: Not prefixing with http://, not using a port in the URL, running on a different port, trying a different API call like Post, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the User-Agent?

Comment: Like this? requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/, headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'something' }) What would I set it to?

Comment: Hard to know for sure, but everyone likes to pretend to be Mozilla: `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}`

Comment: I tried this but no dice :/

Comment: Try the Sesame Street school of debugging - one of these things is not like the other. There appears to be some difference between the working request and the non-working one, have to find it. 2 possible approaches come to mind: look at the server side (maybe logs?) and see what was received by the server or look at the client side (maybe Chrome developer tools) and see what was sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is struggling with this as well, what finally worked was running the application on my local network ip.

I.e., I just opened up the **web app** and changed the app.run(debug=True) line to app.run(host="my.ip.address", debug = True).

I'm guessing the requests library perhaps was trying to protect me from a localhost attack? Or our corporate proxy or firewall was preventing communication from unknown apps to the 127 address. I had set NO_PROXY to include the 127.0.0.1 address, so I don't think that was the problem. In the end I'm not really sure why it is working now, but I'm glad that it is.

Answer (score 1):

Is `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` your localhost? If so, try `'http://localhost:5000'` instead

Comment: It is my localhost. I tried what you said and I'm getting a 404 now.

Comment: Yes. It returns 200 (ok/success)

Comment: Ok, what does your response say about the 503 error if you get the text?
`print(str(response.text))`

Comment: Pretty generic 503 error, I can't post pictures yet but here is the wall of text:

Comment: A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
For assistance, contact your network support team.

Comment: Update: when I use urllib.request.ProxyHandler({}) I get the data. However I can't do a put or post this way, I need to use requests still. When I try specifying the proxies for requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', proxies= { proxy info here } ) it does not work.

Comment: My proxies are set of course. Specifying the proxy as a param for requests.get does not work, but using a ProxyHandler with urllib.request does work

Comment: Does `requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', proxies=urllib.getproxies())` work as well?

Comment: No, requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', proxies = urllib.request.getproxies()) still returns a 503.